# When i am sync with gradle file on a android app i am facing below error.. Can any one solve this

Tags: android

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.paytm:pgplussdk:1.4.4.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Comment: try to clean the project and rebuild again or check your internet Connectivity

Comment: same problem did you find any solution ?